# Express + Node. js partial

Tags: node.js, express

проблема не выводит виджет (partial)  в шаблон houme

houme

```
<h1>Добро пожаловать на сайт турфирмы</h1>
{{>weather}}
```

server

```
function getWeatherData(){
    return {
        locations: [{
            name:'Protland',
            forecatUrl: 'http://www.wunderground.com/US/OR/Portland.html',
            iconUrl: 'http://..icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/cloudy.gif',
            weather:'Cloudy',
            temp: '54.1 F (12.3 C)'
        },
        {
            name: 'Band',
            forecatUrl: 'http://www.wunderground.com/US/OR/Band.html',
            iconUrl: 'http://..icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/rain.gif',
            weather:'Rain',
            temp: '55.0 F (12.8 C)'   
        },

        {
            name: 'Minsanita',
            forecatUrl: 'http://www.wunderground.com/US/OR/Minzanita.html',
            iconUrl: 'http://..icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/rain.gif',
            weather:'Rain',
            temp: '55.0 F (12.8 C)'  
        }]
    };
}
//Виджет
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if (!res.locals.partials) res.locals.partials = {};
    res.locals.partials.weatherContext = getWeatherData();
    next();
});
```

views/partial/weather

```
<div class="weatherWidget">
    {{#each partials.weatherContext.locations}}
        <div class="location">
            <h3>{{name}}</h3>
            <a href="{{forecastUrl}}"><img src="{{iconUrl}}" alt="{{weather}}">{{weather}}, {{temp}}</a>
        </div>
    {{/each}}

<small>Источник: <a href="http://wanderground.com">Weather Ground</a></small>
</div>
```

**Это пример с учебника. Почему не работает не пойму. Шаблон с ссылкой выводит нормально все что находиться в блоке each  вообще не выводит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уххх, как весело:)

Вы используете шаблонный менеджер **`handlebars`**.
Обычный пакет `handlebars` у Вас уже 99% стоит, но сверху еще надо сделать вот так

```
npm i hbs
```

Добавляем в какую-нибудь корневую для рэндэров `middleware` следующий код

```
const hbs = require('hbs'); // лучше вне middleware
// папка с partials!!
hbs.registerPartial('weather', fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../views/partials/weather.hbs', 'utf8'));
```

Обратите внимание на строку с путем - начинается со слеша, задается относительно файла, в котором находится.

После указанных выше манипуляций у меня Ваш пример, хоть чуть и упрощенный стартанул. Если Вам не удастся воспроизвести по этому ответу, выложу код на гит, или дополню ответ где надо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if (!res.locals.partials) res.locals.partials = {};
    res.locals.partials.weatherContext = getWeatherData();
    next();
});
```

Поставьте перед началом маршрутизации:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});
```